# How to trigger Pan button from toolbar

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How can I press the Pan button in lower toolbar programmatically? So it sets the button state to UI.Button.State.ACTIVE and back to INACTIVE when pressed again. Is the process same for my own buttons created with new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ToolBar?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is simply:

```
var panBtn = document.getElementById('toolbar-panTool')

panBtn.click()
```